# Properties in windows event ID 41

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, windows-server, event-log

I want to understand the significance of the values for each property in Windows event Log ID 41.

Windows System event ID 41 from source `Kernel-Power` has the following properties

```
- EventData 

  BugcheckCode 159 
  BugcheckParameter1 0x3 
  BugcheckParameter2 0xffffe30f22f99dc0 
  BugcheckParameter3 0xffffbc0b39c7f7d0 
  BugcheckParameter4 0xffffe30f237703e0 
  SleepInProgress 0 
  PowerButtonTimestamp 0 
  BootAppStatus 0 
  Checkpoint 41 
  ConnectedStandbyInProgress false 
  SystemSleepTransitionsToOn 9 
  CsEntryScenarioInstanceId 0 
  BugcheckInfoFromEFI false 
  CheckpointStatus 0
```

Where can I find documentation for what each property means or signify?
More specifically I am interested in `SleepInProgress`, `BootAppStatus`, `SystemSleepTransitionsToOn`, `ConnectedStandbyInProgress`

I cannot find a proper place where it mentions these.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: There may not be publicly available documentation.

Comment: @DanielB ya I did not find any public documentation.

Comment: [Bug Check Code Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-code-reference2)

Answer (score 0):

> This bug check has a value of `0x0000009F` [*ie 159 decimal*]. This bug
> check indicates that the driver is in an inconsistent or invalid power
> state.
>
> > **Parameter 1** 0x3
> >
> > **Parameter 2** The physical device object (PDO) of the stack
> >
> > **Parameter 3** The functional device object (FDO) of the stack. In Windows 7 and later, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER.
> >
> > **Parameter 4** The blocked IRP
> >
> > **Cause** A device object has been blocking an IRP for too long a
> > time.
>
> Debugging bug check `0x9F` when Parameter 1 equals `0x3`
>
> In a kernel debugger, use the `!analyze -v` command to perform the
> initial bug check analysis. The verbose analysis displays the address
> of the `nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER` structure, which is in Arg3.   `kd>!analyze -v`

See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x9f--driver-power-state-failure for **step by step** instructions.

*Debugging Tools for Windows* can be **downloded** here from Microsoft - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/